# Update email with a custom email template in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter mobile application and I am using Firebase authentication.  I have decided to use email template for verifying user email. In the backend, I call generateEmailVerificationLink(email ,actionCode) to create an email verification link, then I pass the link to a good looking email template and send it to the user.

I would like to do the same thing for updating user email.  But I am not sure which function to call in the backend to create the proper link that I need to pass to the email temple.  The mode in the action code should be "verifyAndChangeEmail"

Does any one know?
I found this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links
but it does not say how to generate a link for updating user email.  Does that mean that I can't have a custom email for updating user email??
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same `generateEmailVerificationLink()` method, and, in the page opened via the link, you need to trigger, in the back-end, the [`updateUser()` method of the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

More concretely:

1. In a Cloud Function (or a server you own), generate an email verification link for the new email (as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link) you mention in your question) and build and send an email containing this link (for example by calling a microservice like [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com)).
2. The user receives the email in his mailbox. When he clicks on the link, the user is redirected to a web page you host somewhere (for example with Firebase hosting): the email is then verified, with `applyActionCode()`, as shown in the code found in [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) in the Firebase doc (see "4. Handle email address verification by calling `applyActionCode`.").
3. Then, in the .`then((resp) => {...})` block of this page, implement a call to a [callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) in which you use the `updateUser()` method to update the user's email. In the callable cloud function you must check that the `uid` (User ID) that you pass to the `updateUser()` method is the `uid` of the caller (with `const uid = context.auth.uid;` see the doc).

---

Comment: In your step 1, which function do you use to generate an email verification link to update email? generateEmailVerificationLink() will create a link with mode="verifyEmail", I need a link with mode='verifyAndChangeEmail'.  Please note that generateEmailVerificationLink() in the frontend will generate a link with mode='verifyAndChangeEmail'.  You need to differentiate between generating a link to verify email when the user signs up and generating a link to update email.  Please elaborate some more. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I use `generateEmailVerificationLink()` which creates a link on which the user clicks to verify the email. Since he is the only one to get this email, if the `applyActionCode()`method call is successful, then you know that the email is verified. At this point you can do whatever you want: in your case trigger, **in the back-end**, the Admin SDK `updateUser()` method to update the user's email. The modes of the link are fixed (resetPassword, recoverEmail, verifyEmail): you cannot create your own code. Another approach would be to create an entire "home made" bespoke mechanism.

Comment: The problem of using generateEmailVerificationLink() for both verifying "new email" and verifying "updated email" is that in the front end, there is no way to know if the link is for verifying a new email or verifying an email update. After the user clicks on the link in the email, I need to treat thing differently.

Comment: In the case of verifying new email (user sign up), the user clicks on the email, then the user is forwarded to a page where I call applyActionCode(actionCode).  On the other hand, in the case of update email, after the user clicks on the link, I call applyActionCode(actionCode), then call the backend to update user email with a cloud function, then sign the user out.  If there was no difference between "verify new email", and "verify email change", then sure, using generateEmailVerificationLink() is fine with me.

Comment: You could save a flag in a collection in Firestore indicating for which action you generate the link. Then, in the cloud function you read the Firestore doc. Another possibility (that I haven't checked at all, i.e. I don't know if it possible and if it has some side effects) could be to supercharge the link itself, by adding a query string paramater. Another thought: the "verify email change" can only be called for a user for which the mail is verified => You can get this info easily in the CF.

Comment: If you look at verifyBeforeUpdateEmail() used in the frontend, you will see that it will generate a link with mode="verifyAndChangeEmail".  I need a generate function in the backend that will generate a link with mode="verifyAndChangeEmail".

Comment: AFAIK it is only possible via the JS SDK method [`verifyBeforeUpdateEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#verifybeforeupdateemail) and other clients SDKs, not via the Admin SDK.